# Getting liquibase-changeLog.xml was not found in executable jar (GCP and spring boot app)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, google-cloud-platform, liquibase

Our app is running on GCP and using app engine to deploy our spring boot app. We are using 'spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql' dependency in our spring boot app to connect with Cloud SQL from the App engine and providing the database credentials/change-log path in the application.properties file. Though the changeLog file is there in the generated jar file it's complaining that file not found.

> [INFO] GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] An
> internal error occurred while processing task
> /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>2023-03-15T12:06:00.529Z1050.ue.1:
> at
> org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
> [app.jar:1.0.0]
>
> [INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException:
> The file classpath:/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml was not found in
>
> ....
>
> [INFO] GCLOUD: Specifying files by absolute path was removed in
> Liquibase 4.0. Please use a relative path or add '/' to the classpath
> parameter.

Here is the application.properties file

> spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/public/build/
>
> spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml
>
> spring.liquibase.enabled=false
>
> spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql=SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE
>
> utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
>
> spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = true
>
> spring.datasource.password=PASSWORD
>
> inactive.instances.check.cron=0 0 0 1/1 * *
>
> days.to.consider.instance.as.inactive=90

spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql - 1.1.1.RELEASE

atlassian-connect-spring-boot-starter and atlassian-connect-spring-boot-jpa-starter has 2.3.3 version

Could you please help me what is missing. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml` suggests that you'd have a `liquibase-changeLog.xml` file located at `src/main/resources/liquibase`. During the `process-resources` step, all files in this folder are copied to your `target/classes` folder. During packaging, this should also end up in your jar file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks much @JuliusvanDis for your swift response! Updating to relative path resolved the issue
i.e spring.liquibase.change-log=liquibase/liquibase-changeLog.xml